# libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY) while load WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

This is the code of `WebViewActivity` which is used for loading `WebView`.  I tried the below code.

```
public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {
WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    setupWebView();
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.Example.com/");
}
private void setupWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void resize(final float height) {
   WebviewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
        }
    });
   }


   }
```

when loading the `WebView` I got the error `libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use WebChromeClient (import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;) rather than WebViewClient

Comment: The `WebView` loads while using  `WebChromeClient` But the error shows in Logcat.And when clicks the back button from the `WebView` the app shutdowns.This is the same problem facing when using the `WebViewClient`

Comment: Also ` E/libEGL: cache file failed CRC check`  error comes in logcat

Comment: `@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }`

Comment: I want to make my app without any crash.Can you help me ?

Comment: try to remove the else case

Comment: When I removed the else case the `WebView`  not comes to back.Actually I need to come back to my App from `WebView` when click the back button

Comment: Solved the back button problem.It was my mistake when I called the `WebviewActivity` I have used the code `finish();`  after  `startActivity()`.When I removed the `finish()` the back button issue solved.Now works perfectly.Sorry for waste your precious time